# what are the possible solutions to this equation?

Tags: roots, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to find some angles for my characteristic equation , I need to know the roots or possible answers to cosine equation

$$1-\cos(u)\cdot\cosh(w)=0,$$

and

$$u=\sqrt{\lambda_1}\cdot L.$$

$$w=\sqrt{\lambda_2}\cdot L.$$

What are the general possible values (angles) for parameters $u$ and $w$ in pairs? I need for different modes in general (mode 1,2,3,...)

Thank you very much.

Comment: $$u = \arccos\left(\frac2{e^w+e^{-w}}\right)$$

Comment: thank you but i need some angles , let u=w ,then what would be the general solution ?

Comment: $\frac1{\cosh w}=\frac2{e^w+e^{-w}}\in[0,1]\ \forall\ w\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow u(w)=\arccos\frac1{\cosh w}$ exists for all $w\in\mathbb{R}$ . Actually, there are an infinity of such $u$'s for each $w$, one in each interval of the form $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$ , with $k$ integer.

Comment: For $u = w$, the only possible solution is if they are both $0$.

Comment: thank you, can you say what is the one in each interval [k*pi, (k+1)*pi] ??

Comment: Let's say that for a given $w_0$ you have a given $u_0 = \arccos{1\over\cosh w_0} \in (0, {\pi\over2})$ . Then all real numbers of the form $u_k = 2k\pi\pm u_0$ , with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , are also solutions for the same equation.